# Is this any good practice to nest try catch in redux-saga?

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

This is what I have.. but I doubt that this is any legit.
Basically what am I trying to achieve is that Im fetching an item and if it fails, I wanna to make a post request.

```
    try {
        const response = yield call(axios.get, `/api/cars/${action.payload.car}`)
        yield put({type: RECEIVE_CAR, requestPending : false, data: response.data})
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
        try {
            const response = yield call(axios.post, `/api/cars/`, action.payload)
            yield put({type: RECEIVE_CAR, requestPending : false, data: response.data})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is sometimes unavoidable.
Not pretty, but sometimes there are no alternatives.

Comment: @VipulSingh So this is a legit thing? really @_ @? It feels not right tho

Comment: You can read more about this here, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118788/is-using-nested-try-catch-blocks-an-anti-pattern

Comment: @VipulSingh thanks, gonna read it ;3

Answer (score 0):

This is normal practice in Javascript development. It is suggested in the Javascript reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Nested_try-blocks)

You could also write another saga for failure and instead invoke that saga in the catch statement.